# Missing apostrophe in "It is your responsibility and not the stores"?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe

I'm having a disagreement over the correctness of the use of the apostrophe in the following sentence:

> It is your responsibility to declare your fuel purchase at the checkout and not the **stores**.

I think that there should be an apostrophe before the second *s* in 'stores', as it is the store's responsibility. However, I am being told that the apostrophe is not used if it's afterwards.

Comment: "...if it's afterwards"? After what? You're right, anyway: it's definitely "store's".

Comment: One store or multiple stores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's untangle this a little bit.

> It's your responsibility to close the door not **mine**.

As you can see I should use the possessive form *mine*. So the same goes for your example. But I wouldn't use *and* as it makes the sentence a bit unorthodox.

> It is your responsibility to declare your fuel purchase at the checkout, <strike>and</strike> not the store's.

As @Robusto suggested, it's better to put *your* and *store's* closer together.

> It is your responsibility, not the store's, to declare your fuel purchase at the checkout.

Comment: I agree that the *and* is unusual, but something is definitely needed there to show the meaning is not *at the checkout rather than at the stores*. A comma would do, but they aren't popular on signs.

Comment: Additionally, it would help to put *your* and *store's* closer together: "It is your responsibility, not the store's, to declare your fuel purchase at the checkout."

Comment: Please add a comma after **checkout** for clarity.

Comment: @Robusto- edited it based on your comments.

Comment: @Kris- I added one, but I am not sure if that's needed on signs, as Tim suggested.